# Debug a C file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to compile C code in VS Code, but I can't figure out how. I tried installing the C/C++ Tools extension but as it turns out it doesn't support debugging on Windows. I also tried installing MinGW, but I don't know how to compile from VS Code with it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Seems like it can't be done in Windows, and that you have to use Visual Studio Community edition.

Comment: What do you mean by C99? How is your code different from thousands of other C programs? Are you asking for general help compiling C in Windows? Probably you should install the community edition of Visual Studio from [Downloads | Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).

Comment: @user34660 I included the C99 part because I thought it might be relevant. I'm asking for help on how to debug C code using Visual Studio Code. I want to use VS Code, not Community edition.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp _but if you want the best possible experience for your existing Visual C++ projects **or debugging on Windows**, we recommend you use a version of Visual Studio such as Visual Studio Community._

Comment: The Community edition is Visual Studio. It is the same software that you might have had to pay about $1000 for a few months ago. It is not a stripped-down version. It is a professional version.

Comment: If you want to use VS Code and have a debugger, the official response from MS seems to be you have to use OSX or Linux.

Comment: @Christopher Schneider, that seems to be a bizarre reply. Note that the question title is "Debug a C file in Visual Studio Code" so obviously "VS Code" is Visual Studio Code. Where does Microsoft say to use OSX or Linux for that?

Comment: @user34660 Didn't check the link I posted?  I know that seems odd coming from MS of all places.  _Debugging is supported on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit) and OS X (see Known limitation below)._

Comment: I apologize for not knowing that Visual Studio Code is totally different from Visual Studio. This is another case of Microsoft intentionally confusing us.